performance.timeOrigin = undefined
when i deploy my code Deno Deploy, I have this error in the logs and it says

"ERROR: RangeError: Invalid time value
at Date.toISOString ()".

It happens because of this line in my code
const start = performance.timeOrigin; //undefined

I've tried to use Date.now() instead of performance.timeOrigin, and it worked. And also performance.now() is working as well.
Here's my code
 * @param {number} [precision=6] - The number of decimal places designating
 *                                 the fraction of a second to return.
 * @returns {string} - The ISO 8601 timestamp with microsecond precision.
 */

const Timestamp = function (precision = 6) {

  if (!type.int(precision)) precision = 6;
  const p = precision;

  // Current process start time and performance increment in milliseconds
  const start = performance.timeOrigin;
  const now = performance.now();
  
  // Create an ISO 8601 string from the total milliseconds
  const iso = new Date(start + now).toISOString();
  
  // Extract microseconds and convert to string
  const microseconds = (((start + now) % 1000) / 1000).toFixed(p).slice(2);

  // Modify the ISO 8601 string to include microseconds
  return iso.substring(0, iso.indexOf('.') + 1) + microseconds + 'Z';

};



/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Export
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

export default Timestamp;


The code runs in Chrome and other environments if you change if (!type.int(precision)) to  if (!Number.isInteger(precision)) but do some simple debugging like console.log(performance.timeOrigin)

@mplungjan thank u for answer. I changed what u said and did logging, but still the same
performance.now is fine see digits, performance.timeOrigin is undefined

@Ruslan I see you created a GitHub issue for this, so I'm linking it here for other viewers: denoland/deploy_feedback#696.

You can create a Deno Deploy playground from the code in this TypeScript Playground to naively examine the property types of various global objects if the API reference isn't satisfactory. It appears that — in the Deploy runtime — the key "timeOrigin" exists in performance, but its value is undefined.
